# Prevent "back" behavior on mac trackpad on an element with horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If you scroll in one direction very hard in mac, [it will trigger back/forward navigation behavior.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21547?locale=en_US).

I have a component which is largely dependent on horizontal scrolling behavior. However, if you scroll *too hard* and hit the edge, it will trigger a back or forward behavior. For a good user experience, I am trying to disable this while scrolling. This is how I started:

```
export default class FilmRoll extends Component {
  onScroll = ({ scrollLeft, scrollRight, target }) => {
    // not sure what to do next
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onScroll={this.onScroll}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do you prevent this default behavior in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

you can add `overflow-x: scroll;` (or auto) and `overscroll-behavior-x: contain;` to prevent the navigation when scrolling with the trackpad

Comment: this is not working right on 10 Feb 2023 .. can you share a demo please?